# Performance drop on partial rendering when migrating app from Rails 2.3.5 to 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3

I just migrated [Guzzle](http://guzzle.it) from Rails 2.3.5 to 3.0.6 and installed the app package on a new server. And I have a performance drop on pages that have many partials to render.

Both hardware are the same (8 core 8GB + SSD server) and these are the only differences:

Current machine runs Ubuntu 10.4 LTS 64 bits, REE (Ruby Enterprise Edition) 64 bits and the app is built on Rails 2.3.5.

New machine runs Ubuntu 10.10 32bits, REE 32 bits and the app is built on Rails 3.

(the reason why I'm running the 32 bits version of REE is because the 64 bits version sucks up to twice as much RAM for every ruby process).

Both machines are running Apache, MySQL, and Memcached.

Oh and I did add this line to production.rb:
`config.cache_template_loading = true`

Even though I read it does nothing on a Rails 3 app, I found it actually speeds up page rendering on subsequent refreshes. Hum...

Why is this slower, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is MySQL tuned with the same parameters on both instances? It is easy to forget to give MySQL more buffer memory and it is fairly slow in its default settings.

Comment: Yes it is, and oddly enough the pages that are the "slowest" to render aren't the most DB intensive. Also most content is cached (memcached) and Full-text queries are handled by Sphinx.

Comment: Are you using HAML or some other non-ERB template system? The Rails 3 version may be slower.

Comment: Yep. I use HAML, but why would the HAML gem 3.0.25 be slower than version 2.2.22?

Comment: When you're dealing with something curious like this, maybe you have to dig around and benchmark HAML vs. ERB to see if that's the problem.

Comment: Instead of looking and comparing HAML vs ERB, where ERB obviously will win, i would propose using Slim (http://slim-lang.com). But, normally in production views are compiled and cached so the difference would be small, i presume.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed similar behavior in development environment, but not in production - it's usually blazing fast there.
How do you measure your performance? How do you know it's from rendering partials?
Also I would strongly suggest migrating to ruby 1.9.2 (REE is 1.8.7 if I'm not mistaken).
1.9.2 should give a considerable performance boost across the board.

Comment: I'm both checking individual requests and using ab. Checking the production log on the Rails 3 app shows that it spends quite some time on some partials (and not necessarily those expected). REE is based on 1.8.7 and you are right maybe I could give Ruby 1.9 a try. That being said, the current machine is rubbing REE and I can't complain about performances.

Answer (score 0):

Originally `cache_template_loading` was removed, for simplicity, but was later re-introduced. So it surely has an effect in rails3.

But to have caching, you will have to set

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.cache_template_loading = true
```

(not sure what the `line` means you are referring to). But note that you have to set both to true to have caching (i get that from [the commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e89fff2f6b815529cf729fc8e900a8275c9514e8), especially the tests).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Of course @nathanvda, but cache_classes hasn't been removed from the default production.rb file in Rails 3 that's why I haven't mentioned it.

Comment: Indeed, by default that is the case, just making sure, because it is only this specific combination that enables the caching. Otherwise i have no idea ;)

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't `line` but `true` of course :) I just saw I made a typo!